# How to parse event start time on fullcalendar event.start method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, fullcalendar

Hello I'm using the fullcalendar jQuery plugin to create a calendar app. When I call the start method on the event object the date format I get is like this:

> ISO FORMAT:
>
> Sun Nov 27 2011 06:30:00 GMT+0200 (EET)

Now I want to keep only the time and minutes of the event:

> 6 hours
>
> 30 minutes

in our example.

How can I trim/parse only the time with JavaScript?

Comment: Also If I want to parse the day "Sun"? Because the getDay method returns the day as digit 0-6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Date.parse:

```
var your_date = "Sun Nov 27 2011 06:30:00 GMT+0200 (EET)";
var t = Date.parse(your_date); // date in milliseconds since January 1, 1970
var d = new Date(t);
d.getHours(); // 6 hours
d.getMinutes(); // 30 minutes
```

Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp to more JavaScript Date options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Date.parse` but when used with `new Date` you obtain a Date object in the **current timezone**, so with different hour values on different computers.

A more robust option is using regular expressions. If the format is always like you posted, then the hours can be obtained by this regular expression:

```
/ (\d+):/
```

which means:

1. a space
2. one or more digits
3. a colon

For the minutes it is something similar, but those are surrounded with a colon at both sides:

```
/:(\d+):/
```

You can then parse the numbers out via `.exec(str)[1]`, where `1` is group 1, defined with the parens.

Converting to a number can be done using `+str`:

```
var str     = "Sun Nov 27 2011 06:30:00 GMT+0200 (EET)",
    hours   = +/ (\d+):/.exec(str)[1]; // 6
    minutes = +/:(\d+):/.exec(str)[1]; // 30
```

Comment: For simple matching, use `String.prototype.match(RegExp)`, not `RegExp.prototype.exec(String)`:
`var hours = +(str.match(/ (\d+):/) || [, NaN])[1];`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a bit complex, because you can simply use the string in the javascript `Date()` constructor like this:

```
var d = new Date("Sun Nov 27 2011 06:30:00 GMT+0200 (EET)");
```

But doing a call to `d.getHours()` will probably not result in the value you wanted to get, because JavaScript converts the date to your local timezone. For example, doing `alert(d)` for me in Germany results in:

```
Sun Nov 27 2011 05:30:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

If that is what you wanted, you're done. Otherwise, you will need to convert it the the timezone wanted.

Comment: Now it's ok, because it's calendar I want the each local time :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not much into jQuery (I try to avoid it), so I assume they did the right thing and stored a `Date` instance.  If that is the case, you are only seeing the (localized) **string representation** of that `Date` instance (as if you called its `toString()` method), and you can retrieve the components using its prototype methods:

```
var d = jQuery(…).whatever(…);
var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();
```

or

```
var hours = d.getUTCHours();
var minutes = d.getUTCMinutes();
```

depending on what you are interested in.  No parsing necessary.